# How to make a tcolorbox with only a left side rule?

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=red,frame empty,leftrule=1pt]
Hello, world!
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. But I can't understand, what is the right combination of options so that only the left rule is visible, while all others are hidden.

BTW, if I remove `frame empty` and set `rightrule=0pt` and so on, I still see a thin border around the box, as [explained here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616575/how-to-draw-tcolorbox-without-a-frame).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512501/create-a-box-using-the-tcolorbox-package-or-any-o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a box using the tcolorbox package or any other? (image)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512501/create-a-box-using-the-tcolorbox-package-or-any-other-image)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,sharp corners,enhanced,borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{red}]
Hello, world!
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you know how to remove the background color too?

Comment: `interior hidden`.