# Add citation levels, like in e-mails

Tags: citing, environments, bar

I am writing a report, in which I would like to cite some text and theorems, and I am wondering if there is an easy way to add a left bar to these citations, like in e-mails or the code below, to visually separate them from the main text? Ideally some environment like:

> \begin{citation}
> …
> \end{citation}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use the tcolorbox package to create a new environment with a bar on the left side, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616587/36296

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!