`roundcorner` don't work even with example in docs?
As the title, the example of package mdframed with roundcorner option doesn't work.
Here below the mwe:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xcolor]{mdframed}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newmdtheoremenv[%
    middlelinewidth=2,
    roundcorner=10pt,%
    leftmargin=30,rightmargin=30,%
    backgroundcolor=yellow!30,%
    outerlinecolor=blue!70!black,%
    innertopmargin=\topskip,%
    splittopskip=\topskip,%
    ntheorem=true,%
]{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{1111}
\lipsum[1]
\section{2222}
\begin{theorem}[Inhomogeneous linear]
    In any right triangle, the area
    of the square whose side is the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the areas
    of the squares whose sides are the two legs.
    $$
    a^2+b^2=c^2
    $$
\end{theorem}
\end{document}




you need \usepackage[xcolor,framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} but I would recommend to use tcolorbox instead, mdframed has not been maintained since a long time.

Ops! It works! I know the tcolorbox package, and it actually more powerfully than mdframe, but with some easy/simple case, such as adding the leftbar, the leftbar environment in framed package or some simple configuration with mdframed may be more easier? I just attempt to learn about the packages mdframed.Thanks to yr kindness!

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616587/2388

It's hard to search the link via my keyword . Thanks a lot!
